# Detecting if app installation has been completed/not completed/paused by user - iOS?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am displaying some apps(icons) in `tableview`. In that tableview, once user clicks on the tableview cell, it would redirect to appstore for corresponding app. Up to this, it is working fine.

My issue is, once user clicks on the download option to download that particular app, how could i know that app is downloaded completely or paused by the user after clicking the download option.

Is there any code to do that programmatically, I checked some forums, but they give us url scheme to do that, but I don't know how many apps would come from server, in displaying tableview. So, it wont help me. If anyone know, pls. give your valuable suggestion. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You can check that either the app is installed or not . (As per my search you can not check either it is paused or not).

Possible Duplicate

[Detecting programmatically whether an app is installed on iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3808691/detecting-programmatically-whether-an-app-is-installed-on-iphone)

Comment: thx for your answer, but i dont have limitations for apps. then how can i give that open url, method?