# App installed or not? Detect programatically in iphone

Tags: ios, installed-applications

I want to detect apps installed on my Iphone Programatically. How can I do this ?
There are many Questions at stackoverflow but none of them techniques are working .

One of them is here [Detecting programmatically whether an app is installed on iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3808691/detecting-programmatically-whether-an-app-is-installed-on-iphone)

In this

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"nameOfMyApp:"]];
```

How can I find the name of app e.g Facebook is installed and its name is displaying as Facebook but when i wrote Facebook its code is not working but when i wrote "fb" insteadd of "Facebook" its working

Comment: nameOfMyApp:// try this

Comment: @anbu.karthik how i get the name of app

Comment: get the list of app installed in your device use this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7226406/get-list-of-all-installed-apps\

Comment: @anbu.karthik not working