# How to open ios app using url?

Tags: ios, deep-linking, url-scheme

I want to open my ios app using URL schemes. I am able to open app using this.
But I want if app is not installed then app store should be opened where user can download app.
Is this possible? How can I do that?

**EDIT**
Explaining question step wise:

1. I have a mail in my inbox with a url.
2. I click on URL then
   i. If app is installed in phone, app will launch.
   ii. Otherwise app store will be opened to download app.

Thank

Comment: Check the answer see if it help@Vivek Sinha

Comment: there is already an answer to that, please see this answer here:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/3808757/1447518

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detecting programmatically whether an app is installed on iPhone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3808691/detecting-programmatically-whether-an-app-is-installed-on-iphone)

Comment: I want to open it from a url not from any other app. Above link is not what I want.

Comment: You may find tutorial here   https://medium.com/@abhimuralidharan/universal-links-in-ios-79c4ee038272

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I handled it via my server side code:

```
if ((navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)) || (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i))) {
location.replace("com.myapp://");
setTimeout(function() {
                if (!document.webkitHidden) {
                    location.replace("https://itunes.apple.com/app/xxxxxxxx");
                }
            }, 25);}
else if ((navigator.userAgent.match(/android/i)) || (navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i))) {
location.replace("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=packagename&hl=en");}
else  {
location.replace("http://www.example.com");}
```

I put this in my www.mysite.com/download page & share this url via campaigns.

Comment: How to avoid the open confirmation dialog?

Answer (score 5):

What you're describing is called Deferred Deep Linking (`Deep Linking` refers to using a link to open your app, even directly to a specific piece of content, and `Deferred` means that it works even if the app isn't installed first).

Unfortunately there's no native way to accomplish this yet on either iOS or Android. URL schemes don't work, because they *always* fail if the app isn't installed. Apple's new [Universal Links](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html) in iOS 9 get closer, but you'd still have to handle redirecting the user from your website to the App Store

A free service like [Branch.io](https://branch.io) (full disclosure: they're so awesome I work with them) can handle all of this for you though. Here's the docs page covering exactly how to create email links like you described: https://dev.branch.io/features/email-campaigns/overview/

Comment: any idea on how to handle redirecting the user from our browser to the App Store link ?

Comment: By 'our browser', do you mean Safari? If so, you just redirect to the App Store URL (Javascript or HTTP 3XX) and the App Store will open.

Comment: In theory, it should work in any browser with support for custom URI schemes...which should be all of them on iOS. I've never seen one where this didn't work, but I suppose it's possible.

Answer (score -1):

If your App is not installed in device then, you can open app store using below lines of code:

```
NSString *iTunesUrlofApp = @"itms://itunes.apple.com/us/app/apple-store/...";
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:iTunesUrlofApp]];
```

Try below code:

```
if([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:url]){
    // Means your app is installed, and it can be open
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
}
else{
    //Your app is not installed so, Open app store with your apps iTunes Url
    NSString *iTunesUrlofApp = @"itms://itunes.apple.com/us/app/apple-store/...";
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:iTunesUrlofApp]];

}
```

After iOS 5 you can also use `https://` to avoid redirections.

Edit:

Check the link to open app from url if installed: [Universal links](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html) to open app from Url.

Comment: I have just a url in mailbox, using which I want to open app (if installed) or app store (if not )

Comment: OP has asked to open url from browser not from his APP

Comment: can u write this for swift