# How to create a deep link to the Apple Wallet app from my website?

Tags: ios, iphone, deep-linking, wallet

I would like to have a link on my mobile website that once clicked from an iOS device, it will open up the Apple Wallet app.

I know there are some [questions about this subject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35866742/how-to-open-ios-app-using-url) when it comes to an app that I built, but since this is not the case here, I'm not sure what is the right approach. I'm also aware of [Brnach.io](https://branch.io/), but again, I think this solution is for an app I own, and I'm not sure how I can implement it for apps created by Apple (or other 3rd party developers) and specifically Apple Wallet (for example: how do I get the app ID?).

I know Universal Links might also be an option but I've read that I can't use an automated redirect with them (which I will need to do too)

Comment: There is an undocumented protocol shoebox:// that will open wallet, but nobody has figured out how to open on a specific pass.

Comment: @PassKit Can you explain how to use this protocol? I'm okay with just opening the app and not controlling which pass will show up

Comment: `<a href="shoebox://">open wallet</a>` should be all you need.

Comment: @PassKit Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use this in your URL- shoebox://

Comment: How did you come across this information? The reason I'm asking is because I can't seem to figure out how to find the URL for Google Wallet..

Answer (score 2):

To simply open the Wallet app you can use the wallet:// deeplnk, I'm also trying to figure out how to open specific passes.