# How to check if a specific application is installed or not?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uri

I have two applications ABC and XYZ. I need to show the download prompt for XYZ app in my ABC application. However the condition is, if the XYZ is pre-installed the prompt should not be shown.

The twist here is that i do not have code access of XYZ application (since it is developed by some other team of same client) so i cannot use URI schemes here.

I have also tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/413951/3375832) approach but is of no good use.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5746289/determine-if-an-app-exists-and-launch-that-app-on-ios this can help you

Comment: go talk to the client and tell them what's required...

Comment: [canOpenURL](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/canOpenURL)

Comment: Doesn't `+bundleWithIdentifier:` help on iOS?

Comment: @Wain going to client would be my last approach ;)

Comment: @RDC i referred the link earlier it mainly focuses on url-schemes (my pain point)

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad +bundleWithIdentifier: works for my application's bundle i suppose. How will it detect another application?

Comment: You simply pass the others application bundle identifier as argument. (This is stored in the info.plist file. Usually it has the form appname.companyname.com.) I do not know, whether iOS restricts the access for `+bundleWithIdentifier:` for security reasons, but if not, this would be the intended way.

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad sounds interesting. I will try this!

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad `+bundleWithIdentifier:` dosent work for third applications. Works only for self.

Comment: It's a pity. I do not have another idea.

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad :( thanks anyway (y)

Comment: getting url scheme was the only approach i suppose. got that finally :)

Comment: Please check with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3808691/detecting-programmatically-whether-an-app-is-installed-on-iphone

Comment: Thanks @PraWin.S but we still need the url scheme of required application.  There is no way around i suppose.

Answer (score 4):

if you are the owner of both applications you can use URL-schema technique. even if you are not, but you know the URL-schema of XYZ app, you can check with [canOpenUrl:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/canOpenURL:) method wheter XYZ is istalled or not

Comment: thats where the problem lies. I dont know the url scheme if it is there.